# How to enable NGSIv2 in iotagent-ul helmchart?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I received `{"name":"BAD_REQUEST","message":"Request error connecting to the Context Broker: 501"}` error when when I send a POST to iotagent-ul deployed via iotagent-ul helm chart.

```
time=2022-10-08T09:03:18.182Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=d7ed414d-a132-45ea-b4a3-38ee14a828dc | trans=d7ed414d-a132-45ea-b4a3-38ee14a828dc | op=IoTAgentNGSI.Request | from=n/a | srv=openiot | subsrv=/ | msg=Response {
    "error": "NotImplemented",
    "description": "Only NGSIv1-based forwarding supported at the present moment. Set explictely legacyForwarding to true"
}
```

Following the [iotagent-ul documentation](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib/blob/master/doc/installationguide.md#global-configuration) to enable NGSIv2, it must be set ngsiVersion in contextBroker:

```
{
    host: '192.168.56.101',
    port: '1026',
    ngsiVersion: 'v2'
}
```

Since I am using the official fiware helm-chart, I have updated the configmap.yaml to include the ngsiVersion

```
    contextBroker: {
    /**
     * Host where the Context Broker is located.
     */
    host: '{{ .Values.iota.contextBroker.host }}',

    /**
     * Port where the Context Broker is listening.
     */
    port: '{{ .Values.iota.contextBroker.port }}',

    /**
     * ngsiVersion supported by the Context Broker.
     */
    ngsiVersion: '{{ .Values.iota.contextBroker.ngsiVersion }}'
}
```

Now, I get this `error`:

```
time=2022-10-08T18:17:24.614Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=841d2b61-463e-42ff-acd7-d0f4b867b7b3 | trans=841d2b61-463e-42ff-acd7-d0f4b867b7b3 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.DeviceService | srv=openiot | subsrv=/ | msg=Registration error connecting to the Context Broker: {"code":"400","reasonPhrase":"Bad Request","details":"missing isDomain value for registration attribute"} | comp=IoTAgent
```

Comment: Which IOTA-UL version are you using?

Comment: I am using `image: fiware/iotagent-ul:1.20.0-distroless`

Comment: In addition, which Orion version are your using, please?

Comment: I am using the official image of the [helm chart](https://github.com/FIWARE/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/iotagent-ul) `Image: quay.io/fiware/orion-ld:1.1.0`. Should I update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to comments on the question, you are using Orion-LD instead of official Orion. The Orion-LD support to NGSIv2 is limited, so I'd suggest to change your context broker to official Orion newest version ([3.7.0](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/releases/tag/3.7.0) at the moment of writing this).

Comment: Could you please recommend an appropriate helm chart for that image? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure how helm works, but I guess is a matter of replacing in the configuration files the references to Orion-LD for the one corresponding to official Orion (https://hub.docker.com/r/telefonicaiot/fiware-orion): `telefonicaiot/fiware-orion:3.7.0`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By default, the official helm chart of orion includes an option to set the image and tag. However, I have configured it and got several errors, maybe I will have to do troubleshooting. I will try to replicate the environments in the image you suggest. I will leave the thread open for now.